# Change window root view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, storyboard, nsviewcontroller

I am using Xcode 8 on macOS 10.11.6 for a Cocoa Application development. By defaut, the root viewcontroller of the main window in story board is connected to a single NSViewController object, and I can find the segue defined in the IB oabel. However, If I delete the segue and try to bring another ViewController as the root viewcontroller, i can not just drag a segue from the window to the destination viewcontroller, nor can I manully add segue in the IB panel. Is programming the only way to change the window root view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make any View Controller your initial View Controller you just have to select it on the `storyboard` and go the *View > Utilities > Show Attributes Inspector* (shortcut `CMD+ALT+4`) and check on the "is initial View Controller" box.